# codeigniter won't show anything from my producten table

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, echo

could anyone take a look and help me please.

#### Model:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_product extends CI_Model 
{
    public function getALL() 
    {
        $results = $this->db->get('producten');

        return $results->result_array();
    }
}
```

#### Controller:

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{
    public function index()
    {
        $this->load->model('Model_product');

        $data['products'] = $this->Model_product->getALL();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

#### View:

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <th>Naam</th>
    <th>Beschrijving</th>
    <th>Prijs</th>
    <th>Vooraad</th>
    <th>Categorie</th>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php foreach ($products as $product) { ?>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product['naam']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['beschrijving']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['prijs']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['producten_op_voorraad']; ?></td>
            <td><?php echo $product['categorie_naam']; ?></td>
        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

There is 1 row in the correct table "producten" the database is loaded. I just don't know what to do. can anyone help me solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try like this

**model**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Model_product extends CI_Model 
{

    function __construct()
    {
         // Initialization of class
        parent::__construct();
    }
    public function getALL() 
    {
        $results = $this->db->get('producten');

        return $results->result_array();
    }
}
```

**Controller**

```
<?php if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Welcome extends CI_Controller 
{

        function __construct()
        {
             // Initialization of class
            parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('model_product');
        }
    public function index()
    {


        $data['products'] = $this->model_product->getALL();
        $this->load->view('header');
        $this->load->view('welcome_message', $data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
}
```

and in autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

Answer (score 0):

Afaik you have to call the model product_model.php, call it in the controller "product_model" and call the class "Product_model" (with a capital P).

Also, CI doesn't connect automatically to the database, so while loading you have to specify it with the third parameter.

So:

```
class Product_model extends CI_Model
```

And:

```
$this->load->model('product_model', '', TRUE);
```

...

```
$data['products'] = $this->product_model->getALL();
```

Answer (score -1):

Please at the very least locate where the problem is. The fact that you posted the M+C+V shows that you haven't made any effort. Come up with a more specific question.

Check that the right files and lines are executed (e.g.: `echo`), that the data is loaded from the database (`var_dump/print_r/echo`), etc (mostly `echo`... really. debugging 101.)...